# SQL Server Duplication and correct assignment of Joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the resulting table to be like the example Table I have provided, even though the only month provided was 5, I want the table to display all the 12 months even if the Amount was to be 0 for the other months.

This is the query I'm using,

```
Select Distinct T1.EmployeeID, T1.Name, T.MonthID, T1.TotalAmount, T1.TotalQuantity From 
(Select 
    S.EmployeeID,
    E.Name,
    YEAR(MAX([Date])) As [Year],
    MONTH(MAX([Date])) As [Montht],
    IsNull(SUM(Amount), 0) As TotalAmount,
    IsNull(SUM(Quantity), 0) As TotalQuantity
From Sales S Inner Join Employee E On E.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID 
Group By 
    S.EmployeeID,
    E.Name,
    YEAR([Date]),
    MONTH([Date])) As T1 
    Inner Join
    (Select 'January' as Month , 1 as MonthID
    UNION select 'February' as Month , 2 as MonthID
    UNION select 'March' as Month , 3 as MonthID
    UNION select 'April' as Month , 4 as MonthID
    UNION select 'May' as Month , 5 as MonthID
    UNION select 'June' as Month , 6 as MonthID
    UNION select 'July' as Month , 7 as MonthID
    UNION select 'August' as Month , 8 as MonthID
    UNION select 'September' as Month , 9 as MonthID
    UNION select 'October' as Month , 10 as MonthID
    UNION select 'November' as Month , 11 as MonthID
    UNION select 'December' as Month , 12 as MonthID) As T 
    On T1.Montht <> T.MonthID
    Where T.MonthID Not In
(Select 
    MONTH(MAX([Date])) As [Montht]
    From Sales S Inner Join Employee E 
    On E.EmployeeID = S.EmployeeID And E.EmployeeID = 1  
    Group By S.EmployeeID,
    E.Name,
    YEAR([Date]), 
    MONTH([Date]))
Order By T1.Name
```

---

Employee Table (Example, not full table),

```
+--+--+------+
|ID|  Name   |
+--+---------+
|1 |John Doe |
+--+---------+
|2 |Jane Doe |
+--+---------+
```

Sales Table (Example, not full table),

```
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|ID|SaleID| Date    |Amount |Quantity|
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|1 |  1   |5-14-2014|300    |12      |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|1 |  2   |5-16-2014|600    |4       |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|2 |  3   |5-14-2014|452    |10      |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|2 |  4   |5-16-2014|356    |2       |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
```

I'm getting this result,
http://i61.tinypic.com/xnumpz.png

The problem with that result is the duplication, and that those 3 values (The ones duplicating) are only suppose to be displayed on the 4, 5, 6

Like so,

```
+-------+-----------+
|MonthID|TotalAmount|
+-------+-----------+
|4      |757.00     |
+-------+-----------+
|5      |834.00     |
+-------+-----------+
|6      |880.00     |
+-------+-----------+
```

While since the other months would have a value of 0.

Comment: Why do you need a calendar table if you dont care about the missing months?

Comment: I want to display the months even though the employee might not have sold anything during that month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a Pivot which solved my problem in a magnificent way, this is for anyone with the same problem looking around.

```
Declare @Year As Int
Set @Year = 2014

Select [Employee ID], Name, @Year As [Year],
IsNull(January, 0)  As January,  IsNull(February, 0)  As February,  IsNull(March, 0)      As March,
IsNull(April, 0)    As April,    IsNull(May, 0)       As May,       IsNull(June, 0)       As June,
IsNull(July, 0)     As July,     IsNull(August, 0)    As August,    IsNull(September, 0)  As September,
IsNull(October, 0)  As October,  IsNull(November, 0)  As November,  IsNull(December, 0)   As December
From 
(Select 
    S.EmployeeID As [Employee ID],
    E.Name,
    YEAR([Date]) As [Year],
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Date]) As [Month], 
    IsNull(SUM(Amount), 0) As TotalAmount
    From Sales S Left Outer Join Employee E
    On S.EmployeeID = E.EmployeeID
    Group By 
    S.EmployeeID,
    E.Name, 
    YEAR([Date]),
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Date])) As MonthlySale
Pivot(SUM(TotalAmount)   
    For Month In ([January], [February], [March],
                  [April],   [May],      [June],
                  [July],    [August],   [September],
                  [October], [November], [December])) As MyPivot
```